# PhpMyAdmin - How to show current username in Headline (in div 'serverinfo')?

Tags: configuration, phpmyadmin

Is there a way to show the name of the currently logged in user of phpMyAdmin in the top line (div id="serverinfo") ?

E.g. instead of showing simply
`Server: localhost`
showing something like this:
`Server: localhost || User: Xyz123@localhost`

I found variables like @HTTP_HOST@ or @PHPMYADMIN@...
but maybe there is a Variable like e.g. @user@ ?

If not - maybe I could get a hint, where these variables are set in phpMyAdmin, so I could patch it to add @user@.

Tried variable @user@ in $cfg['TitleDefault'], but had no effect.